# Cart in bootstrap navbar disappears after login

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap

The cart icon on my navbar diasappears once the user logs in. I have tried to debug it but i cannot figure it out. What am I doing wrong? Do I need to authenticate the user similar to the login icon in the toolbar?

```html
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <li
            {% if 'dashboard' in request.path %}
              class="nav-item active mr-3"
            {% else %}
              class="nav-item mr-3"
            {% endif %}
            >
              <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'profile' %}">
               Welcome {{ user.username }}</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item mr-3">
              <a href="javascript:{document.getElementById('logout').submit()}" class="nav-link">
                <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i> Logout
              </a>
              <form action="{% url 'logout' %}" method="POST" id="logout">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input type="hidden">
              </form>
            </li>
          {% else %}
            <li
            {% if 'register' in request.path %}
              class="nav-item active mr-3"
            {% else %}
              class="nav-item mr-3"
            {% endif %}
            >
              <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'register' %}">
                <i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i> Register</a>
            </li>
            <li
            {% if 'login' in request.path %}
              class="nav-item active mr-3"
            {% else %}
              class="nav-item mr-3"
            {% endif %}
            >
              <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}">
                <i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i>

                Login</a>
            <li
            
            {% if 'cart' in request.path %}
              class="nav-item active mr-3"
            {% else %}
              class="nav-item mr-3"
            {% endif %}
            >
              <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'cart' %}">
                <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i>

                Cart</a>
            </li>
```

[image]

Before I login
After Login

[image]

Comment: (1) can you see the cart on inspect element - if yes check the styling, probably some js hiding it or just some elements overlaps above it. (2) does the chart still there on the raw html - you can check with ctrl+u, if not exists, check on your backend code. though i feel its your backend code, the cart is under the same `else` where the register button is printed, cmiiw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your Cart item is in the else block of {% if user.is_authenticated %}, so if the user is not authenticated it will display, but if they are it won't.
If you add an {% endif %} above the cart link it should work, and it will display when they are both logged in and logged out. See below:

```html
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <li
            {% if 'dashboard' in request.path %}
              class="nav-item active mr-3"
            {% else %}
              class="nav-item mr-3"
            {% endif %}
            >
              <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'profile' %}">
               Welcome {{ user.username }}</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item mr-3">
              <a href="javascript:{document.getElementById('logout').submit()}" class="nav-link">
                <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i> Logout
              </a>
              <form action="{% url 'logout' %}" method="POST" id="logout">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input type="hidden">
              </form>
            </li>
          {% else %}
            <li
            {% if 'register' in request.path %}
              class="nav-item active mr-3"
            {% else %}
              class="nav-item mr-3"
            {% endif %}
            >
              <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'register' %}">
                <i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i> Register</a>
            </li>
            <li
            {% if 'login' in request.path %}
              class="nav-item active mr-3"
            {% else %}
              class="nav-item mr-3"
            {% endif %}
            >
              <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}">
                <i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i>

                Login</a>
            {% endif %} <!-- Put endif here -->
            <li
            {% if 'cart' in request.path %}
              class="nav-item active mr-3"
            {% else %}
              class="nav-item mr-3"
            {% endif %}
            >
              <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'cart' %}">
                <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i>

                Cart</a>
            </li>
```